# get_absolute_url is not working--gives this error NoReverseMatch error

Tags: python, django

I get this error when trying to user get_absolute_url--what i am doing wrong?

```
NoReverseMatch at /mega_archive/books/

Reverse for 'book' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['mega_archive/book/(?P<book>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\\Z']
```

views.py

```
def books(request):
    books = Book.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'mega_archive/books.html',{
                'books':books
        })


def book(request, book):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, slug=book)
    return render(request, 'mega_archive/book_details.html', {
                'book':book
        })
```

urls.py

```
    path('books/', views.books, name='books'),
    path('book/<slug:book>/', views.book, name='book'),
```

models.py

```
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('mega_archive:book', args=[self.slug])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

html

```
{% for book in books %}

    <a href="{{book.get_absolute_url}}">{{book}}</a><br>
{% endfor %}
```

can anyone point to what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`get_absolute_url()` resolves URL named 'mega_archive:book', which expects a slug argument. Based on the error message, the slug argument was not provided.  Could it be `None` in the `book` object?

Comment: I did pass the slug, I don't know why i get this error

Comment: How was the Book object created? The error message indicates that `self.slug` is either None or ''.

Comment: I resolved it by deleting all migrations as  well as the db.sqlite3 file--and did a clean migration, and it worked. I appreciate your help.